# Call View controller within Master-Detail template

Tags: ios, objective-c, master-detail

I'm having trouble calling a newly created view controller within the storyboard. I have created an app using the default master-detail template. The only simple thing I'd like to do is call a new View Controller window when a specific check is valid/invalid (depending on requirement) (I refuse to use the term "Login" :-) ).

What is the best location to do this? In here (appDelegate)?

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
// Override point for customization after application launch.
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    UISplitViewController *splitViewController = (UISplitViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject];
    splitViewController.delegate = (id)navigationController.topViewController;

    UINavigationController *masterNavigationController = splitViewController.viewControllers[0];
    MasterViewController *controller = (MasterViewController *)masterNavigationController.topViewController;
    controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
} else {
    UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    MasterViewController *controller = (MasterViewController *)navigationController.topViewController;
    controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
}
//Should I call the new view controller object from my storyboard at this location? (i.e. myView)

return YES;
}
```

I'm even considering starting all over without using the template of Xcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need to use different controllers depending on check result?
If yes than there are few suggestions. You can cover your view with some activity view which covers all screen, wait for checking and than remove activity view.
Another thing you can try is making another view controller in storyboard and move starting arrow to it. You can try to login and after it perform correct segue. 
And at least i can suggest to create root view controller programmatically.

something like this.

```
 - (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {
   UIWindow *window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
   levelViewController = [[LevelViewController alloc] init];
   window.rootViewController = levelViewController;
   [window makeKeyAndVisible];
   }
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I never knew that it was possible to move the starting arrow in the storyboard. First stop: lynda.com. I'll stop asking questions until I've been through each and every video about the storyboard and the way views work. Thanks!